# Key was mapped but key is in password, can't login into Windows

Tags: windows, windows-vista, passwords, keymap

I used a key macro program, I don't recall the name of it, but I ended up mapping one of the keys 'A' to something else, and 'A' is in my password so now i can't even log into Windows, I've tried booting in safe mode etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: a classic problem that also applies when a key is broken. copy and paste an 'A' or 'a' from elsewhere, like from charmap or from an essay, another file in your computer that has the letter,  or from a webpage

Comment: also download another program and change it back. they tend to work by amending the registry anyway so you should be able to do that.

Comment: But I can't even get in to windows!

Comment: what if you look at what key comes up when you press a, then try pressing that key and see what key comes up, it might be 'a'. if it's not, then keep chasing, you may find a key that produces 'a' like if it worked by swapping keys.

Comment: you could try also reset the password with peter nordahl's offline nt password recovery thing. http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: haha sorry man I think I need advice from someone who knows a lot. I never implemented a two-way reversal mapping. I also know that 'a' doesn't up its mapped to the up key.

Comment: Have you tried using the on screen keyboard? The macro program might not read it.

Comment: Hmm, I could suggest booting from another OS (a simple Linux live USB key/CD), then accessing Windows' files and trying to fix the problem from there. Perhaps the macro program stores its bindings in a config file? Then you can edit it. You can't find it? Maybe you could just destroy the macro program's folder and see if it stops messing with your A key... Of course that requires another computer for creating the bootable media.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot your computer from PCUnlocker Live CD, it can help you remove the existing login password. After removing the password, your computer will automatically log on to your system without requiring your to type a password.